# HttpURLConnection returns 422 code due to JSON

Tags: android, json, networking, httpurlconnection

Without `postParameters` (JSON string, which is of course valid) everything works fine. But when I add `postParameters` 422 response appears.

`postParameters - {"password":"pass","email":"log"} - result of JSONObject.toString()`

```
URL urlToRequest = new URL(SERVICE_URL + path);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();

urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(DATARETRIEVAL_TIMEOUT);

urlConnection.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

if(postParameters != null){
    urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postParameters.getBytes().length);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    out.print(postParameters);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();//422
```

Comment: What are you sending in postParameters?

Comment: This guy solved same problem in non-technical way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093564/android-problems-parsing-json-returned-by-a-422-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting Android device helped. The same problem with PC: [Android, Problems parsing json returned by a 422 response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093564/android-problems-parsing-json-returned-by-a-422-response)

Thanks to [Shrikant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1352969/shrikant)